# Passing string by value in C

Tags: c, string

After going through multiple examples of passing a string by value in C, I still don't understand why the following code does not work

```
int main(void){
  char *fileList;
  strcpy(fileList,"This is a test line\n");
  char type = 'F';

  if(checkFileList(fileList, type)){
    printf("Proper File list\n");
  }
  else{
    printf("Improper File list\n");
  }

}


int checkFileList(char *string, char type){
  // Do something with string
}
```

This program works if I define the variable fileList in the main function as-

```
char fileList[128];
```

But I can't provide a fixed size to this string as I get the string only at runtime and hence don't know how long it'll be.

What am I doing wrong here? Please note that I don't want to pass the string by reference as I'll be changing the string in the function and don't want this to be reflected in the original string.

Comment: And just what is "pass string by value"? There's no such thing in C.

Comment: Maybe I don't know the correct terminology, but I'd like the called program to use a copy of the string, and not modify the original one

Comment: @gaurav please don't edit and change a question in a way that makes existing asnwers appear invalid. Always ***add*** the update **without removing** the original one. Hope i'm understood.

Comment: Sorry about that. I did add an explanation on why I changed the original post, maybe that comment is not shown here. Anyways, I know what not to do from now on :)

Comment: If it is just not to modify the string: How about a `const char *` argument? You should have the strings stored somewhere already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code

```
char *fileList;
strcpy(fileList,"This is a test line\n");
```

invokes [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)
, as , `fileList` is used uninitialized.

You need to allocate memory to `fileList` before using it. Maybe [`malloc()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc) and family of functions will help you into that. Also, read about [`free()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/free).

FWIW,

> This program works if I define the variable fileList in the main function as-
>         `char fileList[128];`

because, the `fileList` is an array here and the memory allocation is already done by the compiler. So, it is ok to use that.

---

BTW *"Passing string by value"* is misuse of the terms. C uses pass-by-value for any function parameter passing.

Answer (score 0):

In order to allocate the memory for the string at runtime you better get to know the size of the string first:

```
int main(void){
  const char *str = "This is a test line\n";
  int len = strlen(str);
  char *fileList = malloc(len);

  // then later you also have to take care for releasing the allocated memory:
  free(fileList);
}
```

Comment: Please [see why not to cast](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917) the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.

Comment: you can get rid of that `sizeof(char)`, too, as it is guaranteed to be `1` in C.